# Nth term of 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12 ............?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to derive Nth term of 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12 ............?

I tried a lot but can't find it.

This sequence is known as Beatty sequence.

It's formula for nth term is a(n) = $$\lfloor(n * \sqrt2)\rfloor$$.

I want to know it's derivation.

Comment: See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatty_sequence) and the references therein.

Comment: There are infinitely many sequences which begin that way.  Why do you feel that it should necessarily be the Beatty sequence?  Where did the question come from?  Did they give you any information other than the first few terms?  If not... then they tasked you with something impossible.  You can *not* uniquely determine what sequence something is and a closed form formula for an $n$'th term given *only* the first few terms.

Comment: it's given that it is a beatty sequence

Comment: You appear to have given the answer within your question.  What more do you want?

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can't prove that any sequence with first nine terms being $1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12$ is beatty sequence. Indeed, you can find infinitely many sequence that start with these as the first nine terms. So, yeah, beatty sequence has these nine terms but the converse is not true.